# Keeping SYSDBA connection open in C++

Tags: c++, sql, oracle, oracle11g, sysdba

**Problem:** I am trying to connect as "SYSDBA" and then create a user in my C++ application.  The connection to SYSDBA seems to close before running the create command.

I am trying to run the following two commands:

1. `CONNECT sys/<syspassword>@<datasource> AS SYSDBA`
2. `CREATE USER "<username>" PROFILE "DEFAULT" IDENTIFIED BY "<userpassword>" ACCOUNT UNLOCK`

If I highlight and run the two commands in Oracle SQL Developer, everything works fine and the user is created.  The connection is closed automatically and I receive a message like:

> Connected
>
> user "KYLE" created.
>
> Connection created by CONNECT script command disconnected

When I run the commands from my C++ application, it seems that the connection is closed before command #2 is ran.

This is code I use to call the commands:

```
strcpy(szProcName,"CONNECT sys/");
strcat(szProcName,Sys_Password);
strcat(szProcName,"@");
strcat(szProcName,info.szServerName);
strcat(szProcName," AS SYSDBA");
rc=SQLPrepare(sqlc.g_hstmt,(SQLCHAR*)szProcName,(SQLINTEGER)strlen(szProcName));
rc = SQLExecute(sqlc.g_hstmt);
                
strcpy(szProcName,"CREATE USER \"");
strcat(szProcName,userName);
strcat(szProcName,"\" PROFILE \"DEFAULT\" IDENTIFIED BY \"");
strcat(szProcName,Password);
strcat(szProcName,"\" ACCOUNT UNLOCK;");
rc=SQLPrepare(sqlc.g_hstmt,(SQLCHAR*)szProcName,(SQLINTEGER)strlen(szProcName));
rc = SQLExecute(sqlc.g_hstmt);
```

When the commands are ran in C++, I get the SQL error:

> SQL Error: ORA-01031: "insufficient privileges"

Also, if I try to run one command at a time in Oracle SQL Developer, I get the same message.  This leads me to think that my connection is being closed early.  Is there a way to keep my connection open long enough to run the `CREATE USER` command?

Comment: what happens if you change commands to something innocuous like Select 1 from dual;  ?

Comment: The way that I am executing SQL commands has worked perfectly dozens of times before.  However, now that I have to be connected as SYSDBA, problems are arising.  A select statement works fine because you don't need SYSDBA permissions.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After many hours of research, I have found a way to solve my original problem:

*I am trying to connect as "SYSDBA" and then create a user in my C++ application. The connection to SYSDBA seems to close before running the create command.*

Instead of running the two commands separately, I use a pipe to execute the sqlplus commands in the command line.

- `@echo CREATE USER "<username>" PROFILE "DEFAULT" IDENTIFIED BY "<userpassword>" ACCOUNT UNLOCK; | CONNECT sys/<syspassword>@<datasource> AS SYSDBA`

The command is called with C++ code in the following way:

```
strcpy(szProcName,"@echo CREATE USER \"");
strcat(szProcName,userName);
strcat(szProcName,"\" PROFILE \"DEFAULT\" IDENTIFIED BY \"");
strcat(szProcName,Password);
strcat(szProcName,"\" ACCOUNT UNLOCK; | sqlplus sys/");
strcat(szProcName,Sys_Password);
strcat(szProcName,"@");
strcat(szProcName,info.szServerName);
strcat(szProcName," AS SYSDBA");

system(szProcName);
```

Answer (score 1):

Pure ODBC Connections do not, I believe, support the "AS SYSDBA" option for Oracle connection strings.

The solution is to have them connect to a user that has the specific privs you require (CREATE ANY USER in your example), and the "as sysdba" problem takes care of itself.

Comment: Although this is not the answer I was looking for (look at my solution), I don't want to waste the reputation.  You did give one possible solution, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you can user a pseudo user which has the dba privileges granted to it and connect to that user from your script. Since the new user will also have the admin privilege you will be able to create other users or any other task that you wish to accomplish.

```
create user test identified by password ;
grant dba to test with admin option;
```

Now connect to "test" using your script and perform your operations.